# How do I upload hundreds of images in a post?

Tags: php, wordpress, media, multifile-uploader

I want to upload more than 1000-3000 images to a post using the 'Add media' functionality.

If I add them to the media upload window (drag and drop or select), the browser warns me that the script is lagging. Eg on firefox:

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.Script: ../wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,json2&ver=4.1:2

I'm guessing this is expected, as the ajax call to upload the images hasn't returned, hence it seems like its busy.

How can I tweak this to wait, while this particular functionality is called?

Note: This is part of a plugin I am making where the user would be required to attach hundreds of images in each post (like a gallery). Of course I want to use the existing functionality and not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Perhaps shoehorning this behaviour into WordPress isn't ideal?

Comment: I don't understand why is not ideal?

Comment: "Add media" is for adding a few images to a blog post. It's not intended for a 3,000 image gallery. You'll run into endless issues and should either pursue a dedicated gallery plugin or one of many PHP gallery software.

Comment: If I use a gallery plugin it will be the same issue if I select 3,000 image to upload. I also I want them as attachments.

Comment: No, a gallery plugin would be built to handle large numbers of uploads. The WordPress "Add media" functionality isn't. Feel free to keep trying futilely, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour, as most ajax upload scripts send the files as you drag and drop. Depending on the size of the photos you could be consuming the maximum amount of RAM for the browsers (since most are 32 bit).... 3000 images at 1 MB each is 3GB and near the limit. It would likely take a few hours to churn through that much data.

A suggestion would be to setup an sftp account and then having a script import those files. The transfer would take less time. The bulk import wouldn't be all that long a minute or two.

The reason why I suggest this, is that web browsers were not design to do bulk upload of files. Is it possible? Yes. Do I recommend it? No. Much like how I wouldn't recommend taking my ferrari through a 3 foot deep puddle. Your method of stuffing the files through php for bulk uploads taxes your server as well. I wouldn't recommend trying to parallelize it either. You will add a significant load to your server and might cause the site to stop responding.

Doing the upload outside of your web server (apache or ngix) is a much safer, secure, less resource draining solution.

Comment: I thought about that but I want to avoid this solution. I want to understand exactly which is the problem in my case.

Comment: In your case, the browser is not responding due to it using up its computing resources uploading files. Your uploader isn't queuing items, its attempting to open a HTTP connection for each image. which will cause most of the connections to fail eventually. So there is actually a lot of things at work.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81962/how-to-upload-thousands-of-images addendum

Answer (score 0):

You want add 1000 or more images in post means directly upload the

YOURSITENAME/wp-content/uploads/currentmonthfolder

and if u completed means you should add the img tag manually in particular post

Comment: When you upload a media wordpress do lot of work inside (make an attachment/post) not just upload the media in the folder.

Comment: Wordpress create an attachment post type if I upload an image from `media`. In your solution you suggest to upload directly to upload folder. Maybe I don't understand you answer. What it means `directly upload` and `add the img tag manually`?

Comment: you are right.when you add imager form media .its create attachment  i  already told to upload your images uploads folder (YOURSITENAME/wp-content/uploads/currentmonthfolder) and then create new post/page and then add requried images .please let me konw get it  or not if no means i explain with images